# IE 10 no responde a hidden bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

Tengo un sitio hecho con bootstrap y funciona OK en todos los dispositivos y navegadores menos en IE 9 y 10 donde las clases hidden y visibility no funcionan, como por ejemplo hidden-xs.
Saben si hay alguna forma de corregir esto? Estuve buscando y no encontré nada en concreto.
Les dejo un ejemplo donde justamente img del logo debería verse solo en mobile y eso no pasa. 
Gracias!

Comment: Proba utilizando `hidden-md hidden-lg`

Answer (score 0):

Pude resolver que IE10 funcione con mis clases `hidden-xs` y `visible-xs`con las que ya había armado el sitio y que funcionaba perfectamente en el resto de los navegadores. Solo agregue la propiedad `visibility` en mi css dentro de la clases en cuestión.
Ejemplo:

```
<!--Queries laptop-->
    .visible-xs {
        display: none !important;
        visibility: hidden !important;
    }

    .hidden-xs {
        display: block !important;
        visibility: visible !important;
    }

<!--Queries mobile-->
    .hidden-xs {
        display: none !important;
        visibility: hidden !important;
    }

    .visible-xs {
        display: block !important;
        visibility: visible !important;
    }
```

Espero ayudar, gracias a todos!